# How can I access the html text in static resource file in lightning client-side controller?

Tags: html, static-resources

How can I access the html text in static resource file in lightning client-side controller?

I know how to upload `.html` file to static resources and how to acquire it using `<ltng:require>`, but I do not know how to access its content once it is acquired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<ltng:require>` is used for loading JavaScript and style sheets, not static HTML. In order to make HTML content available for your Lightning JavaScript controller, you'd need to structure your static resource as a JavaScript file that assigns HTML content to some top-level property, which you can then access in your controller and include in your component.

Alternately, you'd need to call out to your server-side Apex controller to query for the body of the `StaticResource` and return the data to you.

Here's an example of the former approach.

### Static Resource `testsr`

```
window.myHTML = '<strong>Hello, <em>world!</em></strong>';
```

### `TestQ231776.app`

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="String" name="html" />
    <ltng:require scripts="{! $Resource.testsr }" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
    <p>
        <aura:unescapedHtml value="{! v.html }" />
    </p>
</aura:application>
```

### `TestQ231776Controller.js`

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.html', window.myHTML);
    }
})
```

### `TestQ231776.css`

```
.THIS strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.THIS em {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Oh. It is a pity that it is impossible to have an `.html` file in static resources. So, `.html` templates are impossible in lightning.

Comment: Well, that's overstating it a little. There are (at least) two routes to access static HTML, as above. But remember also that a Lightning component is itself something like a template. Your Lightning component markup *is* HTML + Lightning components.